# Can you explain me why Layout in Android Studio differs from Layout on real device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-relativelayout, screen-size

I try to create a group of folders for each size(`ldpi`, `mdpi` e.t.c.) and dimensions for each folder. The problem is when I test that on real device, the location of elements change. It's not about bindings, margins e.t.c. Device take right layout, I verified that. But when I choose in "Device in editor" my phone, with the same resolution and size of display, the layout there and in my real phone is different, how to work in this way??

My layout if it needed:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cards"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cardHeigh"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/black_hall" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_home"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/homeWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/homeHeigh"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/homeMarginLeft"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/homeMarginTop"
        android:background="@color/TransperantColor"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:scaleX="0.8"
        android:scaleY="0.8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_light" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_confirm"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/confirmWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/confirmHeigh"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/confirmMarginRight"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/confirmMarginTop"
        android:background="@color/TransperantColor"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:scaleX="0.8"
        android:scaleY="0.8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/confirm_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/head_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/headMarginTop"
        android:padding="@dimen/headPadding"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="@dimen/headTextSize"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/head_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textLinearMarginTop"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monfri"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/monfriPaddingRight"
            android:text="xxhdpi"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:typeface="normal />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon_fri_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/timeLinearMarginTop"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/satPaddingRight"
            android:text="@string/sat"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sat_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/myTextColor" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sun"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sunLinearmarginTop"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sunday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/sunPaddingRight"
            android:text="@string/sun"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            app:fontFamily="@font/futura_pt_light" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sun_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/myTextColor" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sun"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/descrMargin"
        android:padding="@dimen/descrPadding"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="serif"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/images_inter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descr"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/interLinearMarginLeft"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/phonePadding"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/phone_ico" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/geo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/geoPadding"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/geo_ico" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/images_inter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/infoLinearMarginLeft"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/images_inter"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone1_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone2_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Running apps on the Android Studio emulator can be useful, but it's better to run your apps on an actual Android device to see how it really looks and behaves on a device. Emulators do their best to emulate a device, but they are not as accurate and the actual device themselves.

With that being said, maybe your app's layout looks different on your device due to your device's screen density and the units of measurements you are using.

If you are using px, elements will look larger in low density screens and smaller in high density screens.

-dp or "density independent pixels", will scale to have a uniform dimensions on any screen. I recommend using dp.

-sp is like do but for fonts.

Comment: I used only `dp` and `sp`. The problem is when I didn't run app, just view layout in "Device in Editor", my Layout didn't equal with my real phone. It's my PC fault, or waht else.. I didn't know@Jose Pena Sanchez